# Validation of default parameters with `inputParser` class

Tags: matlab, arguments

The `inputParser` class in Matlab is very useful to synthetically check arguments passed by users when calling some function. For instance:

```
function [] = TestValidation(varargin)
%[
    p = inputParser();
    p.addParameter('Toto', 'Hello', @isnumeric);

    p.parse(varargin{:});
%]
end
```

Will raise an error if user attempt to assign a non numeric value to the parameter `Toto` (e.g. `TestValidation('Toto', 'Hello')` ==> raises an error because `Hello` is not a numeric).

Anyhow calling above function without parameters (i.e. `TestValidation()`), there is no error raised even if default value for `Toto` is a string (i.e. `Hello`).

Is there a simple way to force `inputParser` to validate **also** for default values or can it be done only manually and *a posteriori* ?

Comment: That you would specify a default value which does not pass your validation function seems counter intuitive to me. You want the function to raise an error whenever a user does not specify a value for the parameter ? You can also use ~isempty in the validation then. I want to understand what behavior are you trying to get from it.

Comment: I want to test for parameter whether this is the default one or the user provided one. @Daniel answer below is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a class, create a subclass which implements the functionality you want:

```
classdef myInputParser<inputParser
    methods
        function addParamValue(obj,name,default,fcn,varargin)
            assert(fcn(default));
            addParamValue@inputParser(obj,name,default,fcn,varargin{:});
        end
    end 
end
```

.

```
>> p = myInputParser();
>> p.addParamValue('Toto', 'Hello', @isnumeric);
Error using myInputParser/addParamValue
(line 4)
Assertion failed.
```